# JSON conversion using JOLT with ARRAY

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

someone can me help? I'm new to jolt. Can you please tell me how can i trasform the below json message with array based upon the position in to the below output json message using jolt.

My JSON is:

```json
{
  "cargas": [
    {
      "pedidos": [
        {
          "chavePedido": "003/0125238-P",
          "sequencia": [
            "1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "chavePedido": "003/0135001-P",
          "sequencia": [
            "2"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "transportadora": {
        "nome": "TRANSPRIMO TRANSPORT",
        "cnpj": "08.689.799/0001-87",
        "endereco": "",
        "bairro": "",
        "cidade": "",
        "estado": "",
        "cep": "13715000"
      },
      "motorista": {
        "cnpjCpf": "26308191833",
        "nome": "ALEXANDRE"
      },
      "carro": {
        "placa": "MZQ4743",
        "descricao": "furgão Mercedes-Benz3"
      },
      "observacao": "informação id Lincros"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I formulate my ''jolt''?

output json:

```
 "transportadora": {
        "nome": "TRANSPRIMO TRANSPORT",
        "cnpj": "08.689.799/0001-87",
        "endereco": "",
        "bairro": "",
        "cidade": "",
        "estado": "",
        "cep": "13715000"
      },
      "motorista": {
        "cnpjCpf": "26308191833",
        "nome": "ALEXANDRE"
      },
      "carro": {
        "placa": "MZQ4743",
        "descricao": "furgão Mercedes-Benz3"
      }
```

I need the data of transportadora, motorista and carro, but I don't know how I'm going to get this data.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, the expected output is not a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is not a valid JSON value, but if you need wrapped current value with curly braces, then use such a shift transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "cargas": {
        "*": {
          "transportadora|motorista|carro": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

as walking the indexes of **`cargas`** list for the desired objects those are seperated by **`|`** characters in order to denote **`or`** logical operator.

[image]